# Perl: Changing values of a dynamic array reference

Tags: perl

Assume you have:

```
my $data1 = [
  +{ id => 1, name => 'A' },
  +{ id => 2, name => 'B' },
  +{ id => 3, name => 'C' },
  +{ id => 4, name => 'A' },
  # .... many rows
];
```

as input.

I want to change id to 1 (id =>1 ) every time name is 'A'(name => 'A'). Is a loop totally necessary?

```
    #  loop

    if ( $data1->[#what to put here?]->{id} = 1 ) {
        $data1->[#what to put here?]->{name} = 'A';
    }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to loop through your datastructure. I used `Data::Dumper` to look into them. It should make clear how it is structured.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data1 = [{ id => 1, name => 'A' },{ id => 2, name => 'B' },{ id => 3, name => 'C' },{ id => 4, name => 'A' },];

print "Before: \n" . Data::Dumper->Dump($data1)."\n\n";

foreach (@$data1){
    if ($_->{name} eq 'A'){
        $_->{id} = 1;
    }
}

print "After: \n" . Data::Dumper->Dump($data1)."\n";
```

Your `$data1` is an array-reference. Its dereferenced (`@$data1`) so we can loop through it with `foreach` and access the hashes within. As we're still using the refenrences we edit them "in place".

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use a map

```
map {$_->{id} = 1 if $_->{name} eq 'A'} @$data1;
```

but it is a loop too.

Comment: Should be `@$data1` instead of `@data1`

Comment: @marderh Sorry. I forget it.